# How to control the height of a table row

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following HTML table and there is a couple of problems with it.  First the rows in the table are really large, the table row should be just large enough to fit the content inside of it.  Second some of the inner divs are out of line with the rest of the divs in the row, in particular the ones that contains words that wrap onto a second line

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .stopHoriz {
            display:inline-block; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            width:75px; 
            height:75px; 
            text-align:center;
            font-size: .8em;
        }

        .stopVertical {
            margin-bottom:3px;
            border: 1px solid black; 
            width:75px; 
            height:75px; 
            text-align:center;
            font-size: .8em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1">
        <tr style="height:75px">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-right: 30px; vertical-align:top">
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Amusement</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">History</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Beaches</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width:75px">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 30px; vertical-align:top">
                    <div class="stopVertical">Amusement</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">History</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Beaches</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width:75px;">
                <div style="padding-top: 30px">
                    <div class="stopVertical">Beaches</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">History</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Amusement</div>
                </div>              
            </td>
            <td>Main</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:75px">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-left: 30px">
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Beaches</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">History</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Amusement</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, Can you tell more about your **first** problems?

Comment: If you view this table you will see that the first column is very high. with a bunch of boxes in the center of it.  I want the first row to only be as high as the inner boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  The rowspan is causing the problem and I had to remove the rowspan and use a negative margin on the second row instead.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .stopHoriz {
            display:inline-block; 
            border: 1px solid black; 
            width:75px; 
            height:75px; 
            text-align:center;
            font-size: .8em;
        }

        .stopVertical {
            margin-bottom:3px;
            border: 1px solid black; 
            width:75px; 
            height:75px; 
            text-align:center;
            font-size: .8em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table border="1">
        <tr style="height:75px;">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-right: 30px; vertical-align:top">
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Amusement</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">History</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Beaches</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" style="width:75px;">
                <div style="padding-top: 30px">
                    <div class="stopVertical">Beaches</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">History</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Amusement</div>
                </div>              
            </td>
            <td>Main</td>
            <td style="width:75px">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 30px; vertical-align:top; margin-top: -83px">
                    <div class="stopVertical">Amusement</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">History</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopVertical">Beaches</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:75px">
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-left: 30px">
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Beaches</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Museum</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Onset</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Marine Encounters</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">History</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Zoo</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">State Park</div>
                    <div class="stopHoriz">Amusement</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```